# Using Blueprint CSS, how do we style 3 columns, each 300px wide, with 15px margins or paddings in between?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

The width of the content-area is 960px, with 3 columns, each 300px, so total 900px, and with padding / margin of 15px between columns, which is total 30px,
and finally, to the left of 1st column there should be 15px padding / margin, and to the right of the 3rd column, the same.  So total is also 30px.

900px + 30px + 30px will be 960px.

How to do that in Blueprint / CSS?   This can be done using simple CSS, but the coding standard requires using Blueprint CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can override Blueprint classes, see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/aznVd/

I assume you're using Blueprint's `grid.css`.

Comment: almost... except they don't have 15px to the left most column and right most column?

Comment: You must choose whether you decrease the width of left and right most columns or add 30px to the container. I assume you choose to add 30px  to container. Here is the update: http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/aznVd/3/